# Non-default values for postgres-hll type (HyperLogLog)

Tags: postgresql

The [postgres-hll doc](https://github.com/citusdata/postgresql-hll#defaults) states that the default values for its parameters can be changed:

> In all the examples above, the type hll has been used without adornment. This is a shortcut. In reality, the type can have up to 4 arguments. The defaults are shown as well. `hll(log2m=11, regwidth=5, expthresh=-1, sparseon=1)`

How do I create a table or a query with non-default parameters? Or I can only set those while compiling the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
select hll_set_defaults(17,5,-1,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It may also be useful to know the value of the current HLL configuration. You can do so by running the below:

```
mydb1=# select hll_print(hll_add_agg(1::hll_hashval));
                                 hll_print
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 EXPLICIT, 1 elements, nregs=2048, nbits=5, expthresh=-1(160), sparseon=1:+
 0:                    1
(1 row)
```